# Having problems with writing URL's into JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file:

```
[[ 
{
    "company name": "MICROMUSE INC",
    "cik_number": "1036425",
    "form_id": "10-Q",
    "date": "20030213",
    "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1036425/0001021408-03-002741.txt"
}, {
    "company name": "VENTURE LENDING & LEASING II INC",
    "cik_number": "1039802",
    "form_id": "10-Q",
    "date": "20030213",
    "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1039802/0001039802-03-000002.txt"
}, {
    "company name": "PHARSIGHT CORP",
    "cik_number": "1040853",
    "form_id": "10-Q",
    "date": "20030213",
    "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040853/0001104659-03-002127.txt"
}
]]
```

I'm very new to JSON structure, but my understanding is that
every single of these are called JSON objects:

```
{
        "company name": "PHARSIGHT CORP",
        "cik_number": "1040853",
        "form_id": "10-Q",
        "date": "20030213",
        "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040853/0001104659-03-002127.txt"
    }
```

I want to count them, so I did this in Python:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    urls_dict = json.load(f)

itr = iter(urls_dict)

len(list(itr))
```

My expected result is 3 but I get 1 instead.
I have a couple questions:

1. Do I have anything wrong in my JSON structure? (I have written them with my own code.)
2. This JSON file actually contains millions of URL's and I'm supposed to iterate through them to download those URL targets.  Is using Python a bad idea to handle those downloads?

I am asking this because even though my JSON file is only 160MB, when I try to open it with text editor, memory pressure goes up to 36 GB.  And also I'm estimating that there are 1.000.000 URL's and each contains 35 MB of XML tables so 1.000.000 x 35 MB = 35 Terabytes. (Is this many files enough to be called Big Data ? :D )

---

EDIT:

After suggestion from Shashank Bharadwaj, I tried to delete [ ] to avoid having inner list, but it seems like

```
json.load
```

does not decode multiple JSON Objects.

I think that the structure of my JSON is supposed to be like this:

```
{
      "url's:[
           {"company name":"MICROMUSE INC",
            "cik_number": "1036425",
            "form_id": "10-Q",
            "date": "20030213",
            "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1036425/0001021408-03-002741.txt"
        }, {
            "company name": "VENTURE LENDING & LEASING II INC",
            "cik_number": "1039802",
            "form_id": "10-Q",
            "date": "20030213",
            "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1039802/0001039802-03-000002.txt"
        }, {
            "company name": "PHARSIGHT CORP",
            "cik_number": "1040853",
            "form_id": "10-Q",
            "date": "20030213",
            "file_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040853/0001104659-03-002127.txt"}
               ]
    }
```

And this is how I'm creating my JSON file:

```
def url_ext:
   #some code to read urls, request those urls and create index
   .
   .
   .

   #loop through each document in the master list.
    for index, document in enumerate(master_data):

        # create a dictionary for each document in the master list
        document_dict = {}
        document_dict['cik_number'] = document[0]
        document_dict['company_name'] = document[1]
        document_dict['form_id'] = document[2]
        document_dict['date'] = document[3]
        document_dict['file_url'] = document[4]

        master_data[index] = document_dict

    jsonList = []
    for document_dict in master_data:

        # if it's a 10-K document pull the url and the name.
        if document_dict['form_id'] == '10-K':
            # get the components
            data = {}
            data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
            data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
            data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
            data['date'] = document_dict['date']
            data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']
            jsonList.append(data)
        if document_dict['form_id'] == '10-Q':
            # get the components
            data = {}
            data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
            data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
            data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
            data['date'] = document_dict['date']
            data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']
            jsonList.append(data)
        if document_dict['form_id'] == 'NT 10-K':
            # get the components
            data = {}
            data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
            data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
            data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
            data['date'] = document_dict['date']
            data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']
            jsonList.append(data)
        if document_dict['form_id'] == 'NT 10-Q':
            # get the components
            data = {}
            data['company name'] = document_dict['company_name']
            data['cik_number'] = document_dict['cik_number']
            data['form_id'] = document_dict['form_id']
            data['date'] = document_dict['date']
            data['file_url'] = document_dict['file_url']
            jsonList.append(data)

    return jsonList
```

And this is how I'm calling this function

```
with open("SECmasterURLs.txt",'r') as f:
    byte_data = f.read()

master_urls = byte_data.splitlines()
JSON_file = open("urls.JSON", 'w')
jsonList = []

for line in master_urls:

    data = url_ext(line)
    jsonList.append(data)

JSON_file.write(json.dumps(jsonList))
```

And I can figure out how should I modify my code. I feel like I have written my code very complicated first place, speacially last part where I filter 10 - K 's and 10 - Q's and I can't figure out how to change it to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So the structure inside of the json files may vary.
In your case, you see that there is a list inside of a list.
So when you do actually load the json file into urls_dict, it has json objects inside two lists. So you can access the inner list and then you would get the result you want.

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    urls_dict = json.load(f)

urls_dict = urls_dict[0]
itr = iter(urls_dict)

len(list(itr))
```

So when you do urls_dict[0], it accesses the inner list (which has an index 0) thus eliminating nested lists.

Comment: @user:12062373  After deleting [ ] , it return an error :
 " Extra data: line 1 column 3476 (char 3475) ". 

I tried to explain what might initial be the problem of my code, and I think its related to my JSON structure.

Comment: Okay I just edited my answer, why do you want to complicate it? You can use the one liner to eliminate the extra list after loading it into urls_dict

Comment: Leave your json file as it was when you initially asked the question and add this line
urls_dict = urls_dict[0]
after loading

Comment: @user:12062373 again I only got 19 as an output.

Comment: You mean you got 19 as output when there is a lot more? Show the whole json file so we know what the structure is like